# Is Solr's LTR plugin practical for large models?

Tags: machine-learning, solr, ranking

When using the SOLR LTR Plugin's `MultipleAdditiveTreesModel` and `NeuralNetworkModel` classes, your model is defined in JSON config that is loaded into a model store.

It is my understanding that complex tree-models and neural-network (NN) models can get *very* large if serialised into JSON. I think certain NN models could be comfortably >500MB when serialised to JSON.

The documentation for the plugin acknowledges that loading "large" models can fail to load because of a Zookeeper limit (ref: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/learning-to-rank.html#using-large-models). When clicking through to a possible fix, it says that the limit is by default 1MB (!?).

Should the Solr LTR plugin only be used for simple use-cases where you can keep your model simple enough to be <10MB when serialised?

Answer (score 0):

According to Solr LTR documentation you can use `DefaultWrapperModel` and place your model file on disk:

Add path to models in the lib section of solrconfig:

```
<lib dir="/path/to" regex="models" />
```

Then, configure your model:

```
{
  "store" : "largeModelsFeatureStore",
  "name" : "myWrapperModel",
  "class" : "org.apache.solr.ltr.model.DefaultWrapperModel",
  "params" : {
    "resource" : "myModel.json"
  }
}
```

And access your model in reranking query as `model=myWrapperModel`.

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/learning-to-rank.html#using-large-models